# Long installing ri documentation for rails-4.0.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm have two machines with Ubuntu and Debian.
I installed RVM on every machines, and installed latest stable ruby. But when i'm trying make
`gem install rails` gem starting install all gems and stopping on "Installing ri documentation for rails-4.0.2".
What i'm doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good that it installs all dependency gems first, but strange that halts. How much time the installation of [ri](/questions/tagged/ri) get?

Anyway, to disable [ri](/questions/tagged/ri) or [rdoc](/questions/tagged/rdoc) installation, add the following file inside of your home folder in [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml) format:

**~/.gemrc**

```
---
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
verbose: true
backtrace: true
```

**NOTE:** The `verbose` and `backtrace` are useful, but optional parameters.