# Bundle running improperly and gem install will not install debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, bundler, rbenv

I have a project I am trying to get my environment set up in. When I run bundle I get "An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.2'` succeeds before bundling.". However, when I run that command it installs but has this error: "Parsing documentation for debugger-1.6.2
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/ruby_debug.bundle, skipping". Checking the gems version reveals it was installed but not being pulled by bundler for reasons beyond me. Any ideas? We use rbenv for version mgmt.

Comment: Have you tried gem uninstalling all versions of debugger and trying again?

Comment: Have you use the `pry`?

Comment: if yes you can try `pry_debug`, or `pry-debugger` gems to replace the std debugger. if no, just disable the installing of the documentation.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I'm having this issue how do I disable installing the documentation?

Comment: @Beast_Code please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501251/long-installing-ri-documentation-for-rails-4-0-2/21501766#21501766